# How to add WMTS layer from GeoServer to a map without downloading the get capabilties xml file (in OpenLayers)?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, xml, wmts, getcapabilities

I am new to web mapping and web in general.

I'm adding the default WMTS Italy mosaic that can be found in GeoServer (nurc:mosaic) to my map by following these examples: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-capabilities.html 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html

I downloaded wmts-getcapabilities xml file from my GeoServer's web admin page, simply by clicking on WMTS's 1.0.0. Then saved it within the same directory with my Italy_mosaic_OpenLayers.html file.

[image: how the directory looks like]

And here is how my Italy_mosaic_OpenLayers.html looks like :

```
var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();

var map;

fetch('wmts-getcapabilities.xml').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function(text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);

    var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
        layer: 'nurc:mosaic',
        matrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
        format: 'image/png'
    });

    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM(),
                opacity: 1
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                opacity: 0.6,
                source: new ol.source.WMTS(/** @type {!olx.source.WMTSOptions} */ (options))
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([22, 42]),
            zoom: 5,
            projection:'EPSG:900913'
        })
    });
})
```

This code works only when my "wmts-getcapabilities.xml" file is in the same directory with my "Italy_mosaic_OpenLayers.html" file. However if I were to renew my Italy_ mosaic raster file I would have to download "wmts-getcapabilities.xml" file again and place it to the same directory(by the "Italy_mosaic_OpenLayers.html" file) again.

To avoid replacement of the xml file again and again, I tried to put `'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities'` instead of `'wmts-getcapabilities-xml'` in my code, however I had a blank page. 
I also tried different matrixSet-projection combinations; no matter what matrixSet-projection combination I tried (I tried 9 possibilities, 3 for each (4326,3857 and 900913)), with `fetch('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities')` I always had a blank page (not gray).

Here is my fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/qjcadvzq/15/`

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

In the OL example that you have linked, the WMTSCapabilities.xml is read not read locally but directly from the server. You don't want any manual intervention between the server and the webapp, so it is better to always read the file from the server.

```
 fetch('https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/examples/data/WMTSCapabilities.xml').then(function(response) { ...
```

which can turn into

```
fetch('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?request=getcapabilities').then(function(response) { ...
```

You said

> I downloaded wmts-getcapabilities xml file from my GeoServer's web
>   admin page, simply by clicking on WMTS's 1.0.0

You can copy the link from there instead of the file, and use this link as the URL in the above code.

Comment: When I copy the link location for WMTS 1.0.0 and paste it inside fetch like the following:

`fetch('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities')`

I get a blank page. 

I also tried `http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts? ` and

`http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=getcapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0
` and

`http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?request=getcapabilities
`  they don't work either.

Comment: Does this `http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities` url give you the capabilities file when you open it in a browser? If it doesn't, check if the service is disabled?

Comment: @pavankguduru Pasting [link] (http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities) to the browser opens up a window and asks open with or save the xml file.
To check whether the service disabled, I followed this [link]http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/defaults.html
In my GeoServer
 
Provided Services

    Enable direct integration with GeoServer WMS
    Enable WMS-C Service
    Enable TMS Service
    Enable Data Security

there is no checkbox for Enable WMTS Service like shown in the followed link.

Comment: @pavankguduru However under GeoServer Caching Defaults - Go to the embedded GeoWebCache home page I have 
GetCapabilities:

    WMTS 1.0.0 GetCapabilities document
    WMS 1.1.1 GetCapabilities document
    TMS 1.0.0 document
    Note that the latter will only work with clients that are WMS-C capable.
    Omitting tiled=true from the URL will omit the TileSet elements.

Comment: If it's giving you the xml file the problem is not with the url. Can you add the code where you replaced the url?

Comment: @pavankguduru

`var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();

var map;

fetch('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function(text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);

    var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
        layer: 'nurc:mosaic',
        matrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
        format: 'image/png'
    });`

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code either. If the base map is being loaded try changing the matrixSet to map's projection 900913 or 3857 and if possible try to create a jsfiddle so we can check? And post any errors in the console or check the network requests to see if the tiles are being loaded successfully and add the updates to the question.